# Google Map API and OS Opendata in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm new to gis and having problems with matching reference systems for my two data sources.

I have downloaded some OS Vectormap data which I believe is in 27700..

And I have some longitude and latitudes from the Google maps API which I have inserted into a geometry column in a postgres database using the function ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lat-from-google, long-from-google)', 27700).

When I bring both of these sources into Qgis they do not align. Not as I would expect anyway.

Is there a transformation I should do before insertion into the database?

Comment: Can you please post the link to your downloaded dataset `OS Vectormap`?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me! Here is the description and my download link. Data: OS VectorMap District - TQ | Data type: Vector | Supply format: ESRI Shape | Download size: Between 1 Mb and 200 Mb | Download link: http://download.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/open/VMDVEC/201309/ESSH/vmdvec_tq.zip?sr=b&st=2013-11-05T00:11:24Z&se=2013-11-08T00:11:24Z&si=opendata_policy&sig=YHFVrYov8wG10h9wIUTLtm2BqhZufQZsJAYOOKNrtko%3D

Comment: Oh no. I'm so sorry, I'm an idiot. It looks like ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lat-from-google, long-from-google)', 4326) has the latitude and longitude the wrong way round. I've repopulated the geometry column and it has aligned. I thought it was a standard that latitude and longitude always came in that order..

Comment: Yeah, I checked the data and they are in ` EPSG:27700` British National Grid. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 1):

`EPSG:27700` is British National Grid. Google Maps data is in WGS84 `EPSG:4326`.

Load your first dataset into QGIS. Right click on the file and go to:
`Properties`>`General`>`Coordinate Reference System`

It should start with `EPSG:27700...`

If not:
Go to `Specify`>`Filter`> enter `27700` and selected `British National Gird`. Click `OK` and  `OK`.

After that load your PostGIS data into QGIS and do the same steps for that file. Except the coordinate system should be WGS84 `EPSG:4326`. If not specify it.

QGIS will project your data on the fly and they will align the proper way.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I can't get it to work. The Google data looks like it has the correct lat/lng when I hover over it but the OS data is quite a way off. Upon importing the vectormap it said the CRS was "USER:100000 -  * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.999601272 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs)" and after I specified it to EPSG:27700 it didn't seem to move.. (The update on the fly setting is enabled..)